# django: running tests with coverage

Tags: django, testing, code-coverage

I am trying to run tests on `django` with `coverage`. It works fine, but it doesn't detect class definitions, because they are defined before coverage is started. I have following test runner, that I use, when I compute coverage:

```
import sys
import os
import logging

from django.conf import settings

MAIN_TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.simple.run_tests'

if settings.COMPUTE_COVERAGE:
    try:
        import coverage
    except ImportError:
        print "Warning: coverage module not found: test code coverage will not be computed"
    else:
        coverage.exclude('def __unicode__')
        coverage.exclude('if DEBUG')
        coverage.exclude('if settings.DEBUG')
        coverage.exclude('raise')
        coverage.erase()
        coverage.start()
        MAIN_TEST_RUNNER = 'django-test-coverage.runner.run_tests'

def run_tests(test_labels, verbosity=1, interactive=True, extra_tests=[]):
    # start coverage - jeśli włączmy już tutaj, a wyłączymy w django-test-coverage,
    # to dostaniemy dobrze wyliczone pokrycie dla instrukcji wykonywanych przy
    # imporcie modułów
    test_path = MAIN_TEST_RUNNER.split('.')
    # Allow for Python 2.5 relative paths
    if len(test_path) > 1:
        test_module_name = '.'.join(test_path[:-1])
    else:
        test_module_name = '.'
    test_module = __import__(test_module_name, {}, {}, test_path[-1])
    test_runner = getattr(test_module, test_path[-1])
    failures = test_runner(test_labels, verbosity=verbosity, interactive=interactive)
    if failures:
        sys.exit(failures)
```

What can I do, to have classes also included in coverage? Otherwise I have quite a low coverage and I can't easily detect places, that really need to be covered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to use coverage to execute the test runner.  If your runner is called "runner.py", then use:

```
coverage run runner.py
```

You can put your four exclusions into a `.coveragerc` file, and you'll have all of the benefits of your coverage code, without keeping any of your coverage code.